# appendTo not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a php file in an iframe with a form result that I display in a parent document using the following jquery code.

In the example, there is both `appendTo` to a `<p>` and an input element.

The code works fine on desktop browsers as far as I have tested, but not on my phone.

Jquery:

```
<script>
    $('#order').click(function() {
        var free = $('#iframeid').contents().find('#free').text();

        $("<span>" + free + " </span>").appendTo("#g");
        $('.g').val($('.g').val() + free);
    });
</script>
```

Html:

```
<iframe src="whois.php" width="500px" heigth="130px" scrolling="NO" frameborder="0" id="iframeid" ></iframe>    

<button id="order">'order domain</button>
    <p>
        <div id="wrap">
        <p id="g"></p>
    </p>
    <input type="text" class="g" id="inputbox" name="input" placeholder="www.example.com" width="100px"/>
</div>
```

The iframe contains php code such as:

```
$d_reg_mes = "<span class=\"free\" id=\"free\">{$dm}{$ext} </span><span class=\"free\"> is available!</span>";
```

For testing purposes, if I use a span with an id, the code prints out a message, if available.

However, I would rather use an input text element. The `span` was just for test.

Comment: Try using just `append()` http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0a2/experiments/api-viewer/docs/append/index.html

Comment: You are  parsing raw text as HTML. That is vulnerable to HTML injection.

Comment: append did not work any better.

Comment: How and in what sense is it vulnerable?

Comment: What does the contents of the variable `free` look like, if you output it to the console?  What's `vapaa`?  Your HTML doesn't include elements `#free` and `#iframeid` - can you update your example to give the full picture please.

Comment: sorry. in the script example there was a typo/wrongly named variable. now corrected.

Comment: the id free is a span element in the iframe. the content can be for.eg. "exampledomain.com". without the quotes.  the id iframeid is the id of the iframe. When I get to a computer a can add some code. However I know only how to check console on a desktop browser. But not mobile phone browser. Where the issue is. If I remember correctly then in the console is just the text/content of the span

Answer (score 0):

I found solution that works for me:
Changed:

```
$('#order').click(function()
```

TO:

```
$('#order').on("mousedown",function()
```

Side note;
*Funny or Not the following code did only work on desktop*

```
$('#order').mousedown(function()
```

Posted here so you too can see one solution if you come in to similar. If anybody has explanation and/or better way I am still interested

Answer (score 0):

```
        <script>
            $('#iframeid').contents().find('#order').click(function() {
                var free = $('#iframeid').contents().find('#free').text();

             $("<span>"+free+" </span>").appendTo("#g");
                $('.g').val($('.g').val() + free);
            });
        </script>

    //OR--------
    <button id="order" onclick="onClickBtn()">order domain</button>
   <script> 
    function onClickBtn(){
     var free = $('#iframeid').contents().find('#free').text();

             $("<span>"+free+" </span>").appendTo("#g");
                $('.g').val($('.g').val() + free);

    }
 </script>
```

Comment: Could you please explain what your code example does different, why OP should use it.

Comment: before click the btn jquery must have find the btn. Or you can add onclick metod inline and Define a function.That Should Work.

Comment: thanks for the alternative. to put onclick inline I don't want to. The other I haven't tested but I suppose it works because you put it here :) ...